# Confusion with Elimination of Indeterminacy

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am referring to, say, Theorem 3 in Shafarevich Basic Algebraic Geometry 1, Chapter IV, subsection 3.3. or Beauville Complex Algebraic Surfaces Theorem II.7. The statement is:

Let $\phi: S \dashrightarrow X$ be a rational map from a surface to a projective variety. Then there exists a surface $S'$, a morphism $\eta:S' \to S$ which is a composite of a finite number of blow-ups, and a morphism $f:S' \to X$ such that $f=\phi \circ \eta$.

Q1. I don't know where my understanding goes wrong: I use definition that regular map means defined everywhere. So say $p\in S$ is where the map $\phi$ is undefined and say $\eta$ is just one blow-up of $p \in S$. Let $E$ be the exceptional divisor. How can $f:S' \to X$ be regular if $f(E)=(\phi \circ \eta)(E)=\phi(p)=$undefined?

In particular, I would like to understand an explicit example as in Shafarevich, bottom of page 255:

Q2. Let $\phi: \mathbb{A}^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ by given by $\phi(z_0,z_1)=[z_0:z_1]$, which is not regular at $P=(0,0)$. Then it says that on the blow-up a particular chart is defined by equations $z_0=u$ and $z_1=uv$ and so (?) $f(z_0,z_1)=[1:v]$.

Following Mohan's advice, I am still lost. For example, let 
\begin{equation}
Bl_0\mathbb{A}^2= \{ (z_0,z_1),[w_0:w_1] \vert z_0w_1=z_1w_0 \} \text { and }[z_0:z_1]=[w_0:w_1] \text{ when } z_0, z_1 \text{are not both zero}
\end{equation}
We have [image]

Which works great away from the origin, but I still don't understand how the composition of maps works on the origin of $\mathbb{A}^2$.

I've been told that on the affine chart of $Bl_0\mathbb{A}^2$ where $w_1 \neq0$ the map $\phi \circ \eta$ does this: 
\begin{equation}
(z_0,z_1),[w_0:w_1] \mapsto [\frac{w_0}{w_1}z_1:z_2]=[w_0z_1:w_1z_1]=^{??}[w_0:w_1]
\end{equation}
Obviously, I don't understand why can we cancel out $z_1$ if it definitely could be zero.

Comment: To understand, work out Q2 carefully. Take the graph of $\phi$ (outside the origin), close it up in $\mathbb{A}^2\times\mathbb{P}^1$. Call it $S$. Then you have morphisms by projections to $\mathbb{A}^2$ and $\mathbb{P}^1$. Prove that the first projection is just the blow up at the origin and then you will see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following is correct. Sorry, but I'll be using slightly different notations than what you have above. I think I'm using the same notation of Shafarevich.

I think the main confusing point is that in his Theorem 4.8, I believe it should really say "the composite rational map $\psi = \dots: X_m \to \mathbb P^n$ *can be extended* to a regular map". Or maybe "agrees with a regular map on a dense open subset".

Let's consider the simple example he gives. We have the projection map $\sigma: Bl_0 \mathbb A^2 \to \mathbb A^2$ as well as the projection map $\psi: Bl_0 \mathbb A^2 \to \mathbb P^1$. $\psi$ is indeed a regular map from the blowup to $\mathbb P^1$. I claim that the *rational* map $f \circ \sigma$ agrees with the regular map $\psi$ (on the (dense?) open subset $Bl \mathbb A^2 - \sigma^{-1}(0) $). It seems like you know what the blowup looks like in terms of equations so my claim is easy to check.

Comment: Thank you! By now, I have figured this out myself, but I wanted someone else to "say it out loud" and a clean answer to exist on the web.